# IDE debugging points and compiler optimization

Tags: java, debugging, ide, compiler-optimization

While coding in Java, When I place a debugging point in an IDE and that particular statement is removed by compiler optimization-like declaring an unused int and placing a debug point on that line- how the IDE will stop at that particular point? I have seen this, but I want to understand how is this handled internally in JVM and IDE.